# Conditional expectation to de maximum $E(X_1\mid X_{(n)})$

Tags: probability, order-statistics, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ a random sample of a Uniform(0,1):

Which is $E(X_1\mid X_{(n)})$ ?

where $X_{(n)}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$

Comment: Hint: compute $E(X_1\mid X_{(n)}, Y)$ where $Y=1\cdots n$ is the index of the variable that attains the maximum value, and apply $E(X_1\mid X_{(n)})=E ( E(X_1\mid X_{(n)}, Y))$

Comment: @leonbloy I don't understand how your hint can help me

Comment: @leonbloy Excellent hint. rcg90: Sub-hint: The cases $Y=1$ and $Y\ne1$ are to be treated separately.

Comment: As so often happens, I am the only person who has up-voted this question after it has receive attention from several people.

Comment: Same question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617415/compute-ex-1y?rq=1.

Comment: For the conditional distribution $X_1\mid X_{(n)}$ for $n=2$, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/conditional-distribution-of-uniform-random-variable-given-order-statistic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the index of the maximum value: $X_Y=X_{(n)}$ (the event of ties is unimportant, it has zero probability). Let $Z=X_{(n)}$

Then

$$E(X_1\mid Z ,Y) = 
  \begin{cases} 
   Z & \text{ if } Y=1 \\
   \frac{1}{2}Z & \text{ elsewhere} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then, applying the iterated expectations property, and because  $P(Y=k)=1/n$:

$$E(X_1\mid Z)=E( E(X_1\mid Z , Y))=\frac{1}{n}Z+ \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{Z}{2} = \frac{n+1}{n}\frac{Z}{2}  $$

Edit: this is not need to answer the question, but (from a comment) the full probability can be obtained (some abuse of notation follows) thus:

$$P(X_1\mid Z ) =\sum_{Y=1}^n P(X_1,Y\mid Z )\\
=\sum_{Y=1}^n P(X_1\mid Y,Z ) P(Y \mid Z)\\
=\delta(X_1 -Z)\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{Y=2}^n P(X_1\mid X_1<Z ) \frac{1}{n}\\
=\frac{1}{n}\delta(X_1 -Z)+ \frac{n-1}{n}U[0,Z]
$$

So, yes $P(X_1\mid X_{(n)} )$ can be seen a mixing of a delta with a (truncated) uniform.

Comment: Is it true that $X_1\mid X_{(n)}$ has a mixed distribution?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, see update

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for $E(X_1\mid \max)$.  The probability that $X_1=\max$ is $1/n$. So
$$
E(X_1\mid \max) = \frac 1 n E(X_1\mid X_1=\max, \max) + \frac{n-1} n E(X_1\mid X_1\ne \max, \max).
$$
The first term is easy to find: $E(X_1\mid X_1=\max,\max) = \max$, so we have
$$
E(X_1\mid \max) = \frac 1 n \max + \frac{n-1} n E(X_1\mid X_1\ne \max, \max).
$$
Then you need to show that the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $\max$ and given the event that $X_1\ne\max$ is uniform on the interval from $0$ to $\max$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give an answer based on some concepts and theorems in mathematical statistics, they can be found in Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference. Let $\theta\in(0,+\infty)$ be a parameter and consider $Y_i=X_i\theta\sim U(0,\theta)$. The joint density of $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$ is $f(y_1,\cdots,y_n)=\theta^{-n}1_{y_{(1)}>0}1_{y_{(n)}<\theta}$, here $y_{(1)}=\min y_i$ and $y_{(n)}=\max y_i$. So by factorization theorem, $T(Y)=Y_{(n)}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Now note that $Y_{(n)}$ is complete, i.e. for any function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $Eg(T(Y))=0$ for any $\theta$ implies $P(g(Y)=0)=1$ for any $\theta$,(this can be seen from directly write the expectation as integration), and $2Y_1$ is unbiased for $\theta$, i.e. $E(2Y_1)=\theta$, we know that $E(2Y_1|T(Y))$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$.

Now we note that $E(T(Y))=\frac{n}{n+1}\theta$, we know $\frac{n+1}{n}T(Y)$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and thus $\frac{n+1}{n}T(Y)=E(\frac{n+1}{n}T(Y)|T(Y))$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$. Since the UMVUE is unique (up to almost sure equivalence), we derive that $E(2Y_1|T(Y))=\frac{n+1}{n}T(Y)$ almost surely for any $\theta$. Taking $\theta=1$ gives us the desired result.