# Order Statistics $P(X_i|X_{(j)})$

Tags: order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be an i.i.d. sequence and  $X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)}$ be the order statistics. 
Assume that $X_i$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.

Question:  How to compute the distribution
\begin{align}
P(X_i|X_{(j)})
\end{align}

**My attempt:**
First Approach: This approach follows a post [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007744/conditional-expectation-to-de-maximum-ex-1-mid-x-n?rq=1) Let $N$ be random variable corresponding to the index such that $X_{(j)}=X_N$. Then
\begin{align}
P(X_i|X_{(j)})&=  \sum_{k=1}^n  P(X_i,N|X_{(j)})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n  P(X_i|X_{(j)},N=k) P(N=k|X_{(j)})\\
&=P(X_i|X_{(j)},N=i) P(N=i|X_{(j)})+\sum_{k=1: k\neq i}^n  P(X_i|X_{(j)},N=k) P(N=k|X_{(j)})\\
&=\delta(X_i-X_{(j)}) P(N=i|X_{(j)})+\sum_{k=1: k\neq i}^n  P(X_i|X_{(j)},N=k) P(N=k|X_{(j)})
\end{align}

My questions now are how to compute $P(N=k|X_{(j)})$ and $P(X_i|X_{(j)},N=k)$

Second Approach:  Using Bayes rule
\begin{align}
P(X_i|X_{(j)})=\frac{P(X_{(j)}|X_i) P(X_i)}{P(X_{(j)})}.
\end{align}
In the above both $ P(X_i)$ and $P(X_{(j)})$ can be found. However, I am not sure how to compute  $P(X_{(j)}|X_i)$.

**Comment:** I would like a thorough answer to this question that explains the details of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, there’s a probability $\frac{1}{n}$ that $X_i=X_{(j)}$. Then there’s a probability equal to $\frac{j-1}{n}$ that $X_i$ is one of the $j-1$ variables that falls below $X_{(j)}$, in which case it should be uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,X_{(j)})$. Similarly, with probability $\frac{n-j}{n}$, $X_i$ is above $X_{(j)}$, in which case it should be uniformly distributed on $(X_{(j)},1)$.

Comment: Thanks. You are refering to the first approach, right?  Can you fill the answers to what probabilities are?