# For $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ iid from a $Unif(0,\theta)$ distribution, finding $E(X_1|X_{(n)})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ iid from a $Unif(0,\theta)$ distribution, and let $X_{(n)}$ be the $n$th order statistic, that is, the maximum of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. I would like to find $E(X_1|X_{(n)})$. I have that when $X_{(n)}=t$, $X_1=t$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$, and that with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$, $X_1$ appears to be uniform on $(0,t)$ (not sure why). I am unable to translate these into a functional form. It seems like:

\begin{align}
E(X_1|X_{(n)}=t) &= E(X_1=t|X_{(n)}=t)P(X_1=t)+E(X_1\in (0,t)|X_{(n)}=t)P(X_1\in (0,t))\\
&= t\cdot\frac{1}{n}+ \int_0^{t}x\ f(x|X_{(n)}=t)dx
\end{align}

But I am unsure why it is that with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$, $X_1$ appears to be uniform on $(0,t)$ and if the integral approach even makes sense?

Comment: Intuitively, $X_{(n)}=X_1$ with probability $\frac1n$ as each observation is equally likely to be the largest; the probability of two equally largest values is zero for a continuous distribution.  Otherwise, so with probability $1-\frac1n$, you have $X_{(n)} \gt X_1$ and given the value of $X_{(n)}$ you have $X_1$ conditionally uniformly distributed between $0$ and the value of $X_{(n)}$.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007744/conditional-expectation-to-de-maximum-ex-1-mid-x-n, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617415/compute-ex-1y?noredirect=1&lq=1.