# Conditional distribution for uniform $U$ given $\max\{U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n\}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Let $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n$ be i.i.d. uniform random variables on the interval $[a,b]$. Set $Z := \max\{U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n\}$. How can I determine the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(U_i \mid Z = x)$. I think it must be the uniform distribution on the interval $[a,x]$. If so, how can I prove this formally?

Comment: Is there a probability $\frac1n$ that $U_1=x$?

Comment: Are you asking the question for a single $U_i$ or for all at the same time?  Answer by NN2 seems to be for all at once.

Comment: I'm asking for a single $U_i$ but the other situation is also interesting

Comment: Discussion of a special case in these answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1007778/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843061/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you!