# Improve unbiased estimator of $\theta$ with sample from $U(-\theta,\theta)$ using Rao-Blackwell theorem

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ be rvs with pdf:
$$f(x\mid \theta)=\frac{1}{2\theta}I(-\theta<x<\theta)$$

I know that $Y=\max|X_{i}|$ is a sufficient statistics for $\theta$ and I found an unbiased estimator $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$,
 $\hat\theta = c_n(X_{(n)}-X_{(1)})$, where $X_{(n)}$ is the largest sample,  $X_{(1)}$ is the smallest sample and $c_n = (n+1)/(2n-2)$ is a constant which makes $\hat\theta$ unbiased estimator of $\theta$!

So, by Rao-Blackwell theorem, I should calculate conditional expectation $E(\hat\theta | Y)$ to improve  $\hat\theta$!! 
I tried to calculate this by using that 
$$\max|X_i| = \max(X_{(n)},-X_{(1)})$$

However, since $X_{(n)},-X_{(1)}$ are not independent, I am having a trouble with calculating this conditional expectation!

Comment: Try with the simple unbiased estimator $2|X_i|$ instead.

Comment: Because of homework....

Comment: Why not choose a simpler unbiased estimator that makes the job easier? The improved estimator by Rao-Blackwell is $2E(Y_1\mid Y_{(n)})$ where $Y_i=|X_i|\sim U(0,\theta)$. This conditional mean can be worked out in a similar manner as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007744/conditional-expectation-to-de-maximum-ex-1-mid-x-n) post. Since $2E(Y_1\mid Y_{(n)})$ is in fact the UMVUE of $\theta$, the final answer can also be guessed from the Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261530/finding-ex-1-max-x-i for direct evaluation of $E(Y_1\mid Y_{(n)})$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !! I'll try to manage it with your comment and link