# What is the meaning of expectation of f(x) with respect to the distribution p for variable x?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I first came across this equation $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}f(x)$ in a [GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661) but now I have seen the same equations in many different machine learning and statistical papers. While searching I came to know that its the expectation of f(x) with respect to the distribution p for variable x [ref1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/71919/21471), [ref2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/401484/15973). Can you please tell me what is the meaning of this statement, possibly with a simple example?

PS: Although I have basic idea of linear algebra, calculus and statistics , I am not an expert in math itself.

Comment: It is difficult to answer without knowing your level of knowledge.  If $p(x)$ is a probability density function on the real numbers, then it is $\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,p(x) \, dx$ while if $p(x)$ is the probability mass function then it is $\sum\limits_{x} f(x) \,p(x)$

Comment: Isn't this $\sum\limits_{x} f(x) \,p(x)$ the equation for expectation itself?  Is $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}f(x)$  and  $\sum\limits_{x} f(x) \,p(x)$ the same? Is it possible to give the intuition/logic behind this equation? Intuition like, expected value of a distribution is the average most likely seen value.

Comment: In case this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4050194/312