# Prove: $E[X]=E[E[E[X|Y]|Z]]$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value

In My book I saw the following claim:

$E[X]=E[E[E[X|Y]|Z]]$

Is there a proof for this claim, as it was provided as is, with no further explanation...

Comment: Are you familiar with the tower property of conditional expectations?

Comment: This holds by definition of the conditional expectation !

Comment: I know that [[[|]|]]=[[[|]|=z]] for all z...

Comment: Do you know [the rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) $E[X]=E[E[X\mid Y]]$? If so, you can let $W = E[X\mid Y]$, so using that rule, we have $E[W]=E[E[W\mid Z]]=E[E[E[X\mid Y]\mid Z]]$. But $E[X]=E[W]$. So $$E[X]=E[E[E[X\mid Y]\mid Z]].$$

Comment: @Surb My book only says E[X|Y]=E[X|Y=y]

Comment: @Dan that is not correct

Comment: @Dan: I would be very surprised ! $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is a r.v. whereas $\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$ is not.

Comment: @JoseAvilez what isn't correct?

Comment: @Dan $E[X \, | \, Y] \neq E[X \, | \, Y = y]$. See Surb's comment.

Comment: that's a well know law @Surb for calculating expected value we scan all possible values for y

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41536/intuitive-explanation-of-the-tower-property-of-conditional-expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially being asked to prove an iterated use of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).  I suggest you start by looking up a proof of that law and then see if you can extend it to the iterated version you have here.