# How to justify this method of computing the mean of products

Tags: probability

Take two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is an indicator random variable with $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y) = 1/Y$. I want to compute

$$
\mathbb{E}((1 + 3X)Y^2).
$$

The random variables are not independent.

The method I have seen does the following. First fix $Y$ and compute

$$\mathbb{E}((1 + 3X)Y^2) = Y^2 + 3Y.$$

Then compute

$$
\mathbb{E}((1 + 3X)Y^2) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2) + 3\mathbb{E}(Y).
$$

How can this method be justified?

Comment: Is it $E(X)=\frac 1 Y$ or $E(X|Y)=\frac  1Y$? The way you have written $Y$ is a constant.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

By the tower property $\mathbb E((1+3X)Y^{2})=\mathbb E (\mathbb E((1+3X)Y^{2})|Y)$. You can pull out $Y^{2}$ from the conditional expectation,  so you get $\mathbb E((1+3X)Y^{2})=\mathbb E Y^{2}(\mathbb E((1+3X)|Y)$ and $\mathbb E((1+3X)|Y)=1+\frac  3Y$.

Comment: Thank you. I am really asking about why the method of fixing one variable, taking the mean and then taking the mean wrt the previously fixed variable is justifiable.

Comment: That is a   basic property of conditional expectations called the tower property. You can find a  discussion in Wikipedia. @Simd

Comment: @Simd This link may also be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41536/intuitive-explanation-of-the-tower-property-of-conditional-expectation